# Image Greyscale with CSS & re-color on mouse-over social icons?

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, mousehover, onhover

Recently made some changes to social icons on my site, and wanted social icons to be grayed when posts are loaded [here](http://jitkasimkova.cz/the-grid-snl-performance/) , but when close with cursor to it ,to return their original colours, like i did [here](http://jitkasimkova.cz/2-2/). I searched in CSS, but dont found a class for hover effect when close to buttons. Currently have this CSS applyed:

```
.single .nc_socialPanel:not(.nc_floater):not(.nc_socialPanelSide) {
  width:20%!important;
  float:right!important;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

i tryed to do this:

```
.single .nc_socialPanel:hover(.nc_floater):hover(.nc_socialPanelSide) {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

but didnt change nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Do you want all icons to be colored when the entire container is hovered? Or do you want each icon to be colored when it's individually hovered, leaving the rest grayscale?

Comment: All icons need to be in color just like galeries URL in first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:hover` does not take any arguments, i.e. you cannot place selectors in parentheses after `:hover`.

Your rule should look like this:

```
.single .nc_socialPanel:not(.nc_floater):not(.nc_socialPanelSide):hover{
    filter:grayscale(0%);
}
```